# Web scraping in python using REGEX

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some data from amazon.in like product description and product details using web scraping in python.

I have got the product description. Now I need product details. But it is very difficult.

I'm new to web scraping. Help me to solve the problem.

Till now my code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
wiki = "http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/8129142147/ref=s9_ri_gw_g14_i1_r/253-2172200-7363412?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=desktop-top&pf_rd_r=0B55B6ZXRHCN80WJGE0V&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=0d2c13de-20bd-41c0-9412-48afb21e298f&pf_rd_i=desktop"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(wiki, headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
h2 = soup.find("h2", {"class": "books"})
# print h2.get_text()
one = soup.find("div", {"id": "productDescription"})
# print one.get_text()
table = soup.findAll("table")
one2 = soup.find("td", {"class": "bucket"})
# print one2.get_text()
one3 = one2.find("h2")
# print one3.get_text()
one4 = one2.findAll("li")
# one4 = re.compile(r'(?<=>).*(?=<)')
# result = one4.findall(one4)[0]
# print result
```

The product details is in the table of html

The html is

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="bucket">
<h2>Product details</h2>
<div class="content">
<ul>
<li><b>Paperback:</b> 280 pages</li>
 <li><b>Publisher:</b> Rupa Publications India; First edition (1 October 2016)</li>
 <li><b>Language:</b> English</li>
 <li><b>ISBN-10:</b> 8129142147</li>
 <li><b>ISBN-13:</b> 978-8129142146</li>
 <li><b>
Product Dimensions: 
</b>
19.7 x 1.4 x 13 cm
</li>
<li id="SalesRank">
<b>Amazon Bestsellers Rank:</b> 
#1 in Books (<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books     /ref=pd_dp_ts_b_1/254-7968873-2018302">See Top 100 in Books</a>)

<style type="text/css">
.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }
</style>
<ul class="zg_hrsr">
<li class="zg_hrsr_item">
<span class="zg_hrsr_rank">#1</span>
<span class="zg_hrsr_ladder">in <a href="http://www.amazon.in  /gp/bestsellers/books/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_1/254-7968873-2018302">Books</a>   &gt; <a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318157031  /ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_2/254-7968873-2018302">Literature &amp; Fiction</a> &gt;    <b><a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318160031 /ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_3_last/254-7968873-2018302">Contemporary Fiction</a> </b></span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Help me with a example code to get the contents. Please use REGEX(regular expression) so that I can learn about it with the example.

Note: I'm using Python 2.7

Thank You.

Comment: What product details do you want? All the list content inside the `<ul>` block? I think it would be marginally easier if you chose more sensible variable names too: `one`, `one2`, `one3` and so on is not very informative.

Comment: I'll change the variable name thanks for the tip. I want the contents inside the <li> tag

Comment: Please, use an HTML parser instead of regexes...

Comment: I want to know more about regex henc by using regex in this help me know more about regex

Comment: You want to learn regex or scrape amazon website. For learning regex this is not probably the best problem, since `BeautifulSoup` already has HTML parser which does the job.